# WHMCS Provisioning Module, CreateAccount not activating

Tags: whmcs

In WHMCS, when activating a product, Control flow not coming to my module

created new folder in 'modules/servers' of WHMCS 'xyz123'

and added file 'xyz123.php'

and having a function like

```
function xyz123_CreateAccount($params) {

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($params);
 exit;

}
```

this function not effect any of order activate process.

How i can activate this Provisioning Module 'CreateAccount' function when activating an order in whmcs?

Comment: Did you set Module name to your module in the Product's Module Settings tab?

Comment: Yes, worked by assigning module to each product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assigning 'Provisioning module name' to each product, from admin side of WHMCS it will activate that particular function.

Answer (score 2):

Need to select the server module in **product's > Module Setting**.